# customizable file manager written in PHP

Tags: php, text-editor, file-management

I'm looking for free file management and code editing written in php similar to eXtplorer, that can easily be customized and extended.
Any good ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try look here:

http://www.hotscripts.com/category/php/scripts-programs/file-manipulation/file-management/page:2/

http://navphp.sourceforge.net/

http://www.proscriptinstallation.com/File-Management-Scripts/

Hope this helps.

Comment: There are quite a few written in PHP:  http://www.fromdev.com/2012/08/Best-Open-Source-Web-Based-File-Explorer-Applications.html